# Can't edit Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My model.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
```

My View

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>
```

And when i try to edit i see something like this instead dates that i would to edit.
[image]

UPD. html code

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field FinishDateTime must be a date." data-val-required="Требуется поле FinishDateTime." id="FinishDateTime" name="FinishDateTime" type="date" value="29.10.2019">
```

Comment: I can see only name code in your view what about your dates html code ?

Comment: In order to help you with your problem it would be very useful to see the cshtml code you use for the form

Comment: <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field FinishDateTime must be a date." data-val-required="Требуется поле FinishDateTime." id="FinishDateTime" name="FinishDateTime" type="date" value="29.10.2019">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Create globalization settings in web.config